# After closing a window with a command and reload the parent page, how can you make a div pop up automatically after the reload?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The flow is as this:

1. User clicks register button, opens up a registration page using the `window.open` command.
2. User gives their details to the page and submits.
3. Upon submit it sends the details to the database and then closes the popup window using

   ```
   onsubmit="refreshWelcome()" //used in the form
   function refreshWelcome() {    //closes pages and reloads welcome page again.
       window.opener.location.reload();
       window.close();
   }
   ```
4. On Return to the parent, I'd like a message to popup saying Registration complete just before the login area.

I am unsure how #4 can be done and is it possible?
Welcome_page has the button goes to - Registration page popup - Registration submits data using another php page regprocess.

Did I clarify what im looking for or do you need more information?

Comment: you want to read up on localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an event handler to the closing event fired by the window.

Let's say your window is opened like this:

```
var registrationWindow = window.open(url);
```

You can then bind a callback to the `onbeforeunload` event, for example:

```
registrationWindow.onbeforeunload = function(){
    /... your code here .../
}
```

Make sure that your opened window url is located on the same domain as your parent window, otherwise this won't work.

Comment: do I still keep the same code in the registration page for when submit is clicked?

Comment: Yes, the event should then fire after your `window.close()` call.